# Best way to hide private members in a class

Tags: c++, paradigms

I have the following code in a header file

```
class Bar {
   public: 
      void public_foo();
   private:  
      void private_foo();
};
```

The implementation is hidden away in a source file

```
void Bar::public_foo(){
   private_foo();
}
void Bar::private_foo(){
   // Some more stuff
}
```

I would like to not have the private function visible in the header file. What is the best way to do this? 
I know of two ways:

1) Make `private_foo` a non-member function like this

```
void private_foo(Bar* this){ /* ... */ }
```

And call it in `public_foo` like this: `private_foo(this)`.
This is not very appealing to me because it's not particularly OO programming.

2) Use a hidden implementation class like this

```
// In header
class Bar {
   public: 
      virtual void public_foo();
      virtual ~Bar() { };
};
Bar* CreateBar();

// In Source
class Bar_impl : public Bar {
   public:
      void public_foo();
   private:  
      void private_foo();
};

Bar* CreateBar(){
    return new Bar_impl;
}

void Bar::public_foo(){
   private_foo();
}
void Bar::private_foo(){
    // Some more stuff
}
```

This works, but it's a bit too much for something so simple.

Is there a third (better) method?

EDIT: In response to @jdehesa, and because I like to wear the hat of a language designer, here is my ideal syntax (NOT correct C++ syntax, but one can dream)

```
// In header
class Bar {
   public: 
      void public_foo();
};

// In Source
classdef Bar {   // Notice my new "classdef" keyword
public: 
   void public_foo(){
   }

private:
   void private_foo(){
   }
};
```

One issue is that for correct memory allocation, the implementation class cannot add extra variables (public or private).

Comment: Why do you need to hide `private_foo()`?  It can't be used from outside the class.

Comment: You're close to reimplementing the [pimpl idiom](http://wiki.c2.com/?PimplIdiom9)

Comment: For elegance. I have many private functions/variables that the user of my header file doesn't need to see.

Comment: _"... it's not particularly OO programming."_ Why? It doesn't break encapsulation, it just uses alternative mechanism to hide implementation details.

Comment: I don't particularly like this, but you *could* move all of your private declarations to their own header and do `private: #include "bar_private.h"`

Comment: Seems to me you know well what alternatives you have. Having private members declared along with public ones is just how C++ works, for better or worse. What would be the ideal syntax for you, if you could pick?

Comment: @0x5453 but if OP is trying to cut down on number of headers included because there are a load of types that just aren't needed by a user of `Bar` but are needed by `Bar` then you've made the problem worse by adding another file!

Comment: *"it's not particularly OO programming"* - "OO" has become a completely meaningless term in the last 20 years. It's vague and non-descript, without any strong technical definition of what it really means. What's true is that non-member, non-friend functions in C++ *enhance* encapsulation because they cause private members to be exposed to less code.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [PIMPL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) idiom

Example:

```
// Pimpl idiom - basic idea
class widget {
    // :::
private:
    struct impl;        // things to be hidden go here
    impl* pimpl_;       // opaque pointer to forward-declared class
};
```